# How to add 1 hour to time string with jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have time which is dynamic in 12 hour format.

Now i want to add 1 hour to the time.

I am adding 1 hour like

```
s_time = parseFloat(s_time) + 1;
```

But i dont think it is proper way to do it.

So can you guys suggest me how to do it.

Thanks

Comment: Post a [mcve] please. And since JavaScript typically works in seconds, you may just need to add 3600 to what you have, but without a complete example it's difficult to say.

Comment: The proper way would be to actually use JavaScript Dates, not just numbers. But I guess you could use the `%` operator to get the 12 hour format. Example : `(5 + 1) % 12 = 6`,  `(12 + 1) % 12 = 1`, ...

Comment: Yes but he is considering 24 hour time period

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
var oldDate = new Date();
var hour = oldDate.getHours();
var newDate = oldDate.setHours(hour + 1);
console.log(newDate);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are having a date object, define a function like this and call wherever you want.

```
var addHours= function(dateObj, numHours){
   var copiedDate = new Date(dateObj.getTime()); //cloning the date object.
   copiedDate.setHours(copiedDate .getHours()+numHours);
   return copiedDate;
}
```

Since the setDate() function will change the current object, we are cloning it.